# loan calculator using financial.ppmt method

Tags: vb.net

The task is to have a user enter the principal amount as well as select the interest rate from a combo box as well as the terms. The UI should display the monthly payment in a label as well as how much of that payment goes towards the principal and how much goes towards interest in a multiline text box.  I am having problems finishing out my code.  I'm not quite sure if I'm not quite getting the financial.ppmt method or what but not only is my monthly payment not showing accurately but I can't get the multiline text box info (principal amount and interest amount) to display properly.  If anyone can help or at least point me towards a similar program I would greatly give thanks!

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off


Public Class MainForm
Private Sub ExitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
    Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub CalcButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CalcButton.Click
    'Calculates the monthly payments on a loan using 
    'annual interest rates from 2%-10% and terms from 1-30 years

    Dim Principal As Double
    Dim term As Integer
    Dim rate As Double
    Dim monthlyPayment As Double
    Dim interest As Double

    'assign input to variables
    Double.TryParse(PrincipalTextBox.Text, Principal)
    term = Convert.ToInt32(TermComboBox.SelectedItem)

    'clear text boxes
    PaymentValue.Text = String.Empty
    PrincipleAndInterestBox.Text = String.Empty

    'calculate and display monthly payments
    monthlyPayment = -Financial.Pmt(rate / 12, 12, term * 12, Principal)
    MonthlyPaymentLabel.Text = monthlyPayment.ToString("C2")

    'Calculate the amount applied to principal and interest
    For per As Integer = 12 To 1 Step -1
        Principal = -Financial.PPmt(rate / 12, per, 12, Principal)
        interest = monthlyPayment - Principal
        PrincipleAndInterestBox.Text = Principal.ToString("C2") & "         " & interest.ToString("C2") & ControlChars.NewLine

    Next per
    PrincipleAndInterestBox.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'fill termComboBox
    For term As Integer = 1 To 30
        TermComboBox.Items.Add(term.ToString)
    Next term
    TermComboBox.SelectedItem = "10"

    'fill interestRateComboBox
    For rate As Integer = 2 To 10
        InterestRateComboBox.Items.Add(rate.ToString)
    Next rate
    InterestRateComboBox.SelectedItem = "4"
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

go to textbox properties and select multiline = true

in loop you are assigning new value to textbox and missing the existing value.

```
PrincipleAndInterestBox.Text = PrincipleAndInterestBox.Text & Principal.ToString("C2") & "         " & interest.ToString("C2") & ControlChars.NewLine
```

**Or**

```
textBox1.Multiline = True
textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical
textBox1.WordWrap = True
textBox1.Text = "Welcome!" & Environment.NewLine & "Second Line"
```